# Move multiple files inside the folder to the sub folder inside that folder

Tags: file, batch-file, move, subdirectory

Trying to find a way to move files within a directory into the subdirectory contained within it.

For example:

```
January
|   001.jpg
|   002.jpg
|   ...
|   100.jpg
|
\---Photo
```

```
February
|   001.jpg
|   002.jpg
|   ...
|   100.jpg
|
\---Photo
```

And `March`, `April` etc.

I've been doing it manually, but it can be time consuming.

Much appreciated all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

REM (
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" ') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=2delims=/-." %%m IN ("%%~tb") DO (
 FOR %%c IN ("01,January" "02,February" "03,March" "04,April" "05,May" "06,June" "07,July" 
             "08,August" "09,September" "10,October" "11,November" "12,December") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=," %%u IN (%%c) DO IF %%u==%%m (
   MD "%sourcedir%\%%v" 2>NUL
   IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%v\%%b" (
    ECHO failed to MOVE %%b
   ) ELSE (
    ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%b" "%sourcedir%\%%v\"
   )
  )
 )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

You may need to adjust `FOR /f "tokens=2delims=/-."` This is correct for **MY** date format (dd/mm/yyyy) but if you use mm/dd/yy, then you'd need `tokens=1`.

If you use 1-digit months, then change eg., `"03,March"` to `"3,March"`